# Combining UNION ALL with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could really use a little help with this query.

I have a `Products` table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    -- Additional column omitted
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And a `Transactions` table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    -- Additional columns omitted
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Transactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Transactions_Products] FOREIGN KEY([ProductId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([Id])
```

And a `CCTransactions` table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CCTransactions](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [decimal](9, 3) NOT NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    -- Additional columns omitted
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CCTransactions] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CCTransactions]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_CCTransactions_Products] FOREIGN KEY([ProductId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Products] ([Id])
```

I need a query that `UNION ALL`s all the `Transactions` and `CCTransactions` that fall within a given date range, and then groups them as `Product.Id`, `Product.Title`, `SUM(Quantity)`, `SUM(TotalAmount)`.

Below is what I have so far. It won't compile but I'm including because people usually want to see what you've tried. It tells me:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
>   Column 'Products.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Ambiguous column name 'Id'.

I understand the errors, but am not sure the best way to fix them. The query seemed to be working before I added the union.

```
DECLARE @dtStart DATE = '2016-08-01';
DECLARE @dtEnd DATE = '2016-08-31';

SELECT p.Id, p.Title, SUM(t.Quantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount) AS Amount
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd
UNION ALL
SELECT p.Id, p.Title, SUM(t.Quantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount) AS Amount
FROM CCTransactions t
INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Title
ORDER BY Title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use UNION ALL for the 2 tables and join the result to Products:

```
DECLARE @dtStart DATE = '2016-08-01';
DECLARE @dtEnd DATE = '2016-08-31';

SELECT p.Id, p.Title, SUM(t.Quantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount) AS Amount
FROM (
  SELECT ProductId, [TimeStamp], Quantity, TotalAmount FROM Transactions
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ProductId, [TimeStamp], Quantity, TotalAmount FROM CCTransactions
) t INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Title
ORDER BY Title
```

Comment: I like this approach. I'm trying to confirm if I get the numbers I expect.

Comment: I do. Yes, I like the way this gets the underlying data first before doing all the additional unions and grouping. Not sure if it performs best but seems the easiest to understand.

Comment: You could also try applying the condition: `WHERE [TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST([TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd` to each of the transaction tables inside the subquery instead of applying it to the UNIONed result.

Comment: Yes, that would produce a longer query. Would be interesting to know how it affected it performance-wise.

Comment: With an index on [TimeStamp] in both tables maybe this would perform better than the external WHERE condition.

Answer (score 2):

You need 2 separate `GROUP BY`s:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Title, SUM(t.Quantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount) AS Amount
FROM Transactions t
INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Title

UNION ALL

SELECT p.Id, p.Title, SUM(t.Quantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount) AS Amount
FROM CCTransactions t
INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Title
```

Or a subquery:

```
SELECT      X.id, X.Title, SUM(X.Quantity), SUM(X.TotalAmount)
FROM        (
                SELECT p.Id, p.Title, t.Quantity, t.TotalAmount
                FROM Transactions t
                INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
                WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd

                UNION ALL

                SELECT p.Id, p.Title, t.Quantity, t.TotalAmount
                FROM CCTransactions t
                INNER JOIN Products p ON t.ProductId = p.Id
                WHERE t.[TimeStamp] >= @dtStart AND CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd
            ) X
GROUP BY    X.Id, X.Title
```

Or you can rewrite the entire query:

```
;WITH
    AllTransaction AS
    (
        SELECT      ProductID, Timestamp, Quantity, TotalAmount
        FROM        Transaction
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      ProductID, Timestamp, Quantity, TotalAmount
        FROM        CCTransaction
    )

SELECT      p.Id, p.Ttitle, SUM(t.Quantity), SUM(t.TotalAmount)
FROM        AllTransaction      t
INNER JOIN  Products            p   ON t.ProductId = p.Id
WHERE       @dtStart <= t.[Timestamp] AND t.[TimeStamp] < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dtEnd)
GROUP BY    p.Id, p.Title
```

---

*A note on* `CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE) <= @dtEnd`: this condition is not [SARGable](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-sargable-expressions-in-t-sql-queries-performance-advantages-and-examples/) , meaning index and statistics are of no help. The result of `CAST(t.[TimeStamp] AS DATE)` is not known until you have applied the function to each and every row. This causes a table scan (i.e. reading the entire table in) while you may only need a few rows. If `Transactions` and `CCTransactions` are huge, you will suffer.

Comment: The first 1 has the GROUP BY before the UNION and is not the same as the other 2.

Comment: For `AVG`, that would have made a difference. For `SUM`, it doesn't matter

Comment: Sure it matters for SUM.  You're going to get multiple rows with the same IT,Title combination for anything that appears in both transactions and cctransactions because you group by before doing the union (where there isn't any aggregation).  You would have to do another sum/group by to combine the 2 again.